# franc 6.0.0 not import nestjs typescipt

Tags: typescript, import, nestjs

I am having problem importing franc 6.0.0 into nestjs typescript project. Ver 5.0.0 is still normal. This is the error I got.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bG2Fg.png)

Answer (score 0):

looks like v6 is ESM-only. Then you'll need to use [`import`](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#import-expressions) to import because in your code `import franc from 'franc'` is transpiled to `const franc = require('franc')`, and [we can't use `require` on ES modules](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#require).